# How to get the value of html aria-label with webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```html
<div id="button" aria-label="changing value"></div>
```

Please tell me how to get the value of aria-label, which is a continuously changing value in this code, through the xpath of selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you,

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('button')
value = element.get_attribute("aria-label")
```